# redux store not getting updated and component not rerenders

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a question regarding of using redux.

1. My initial state for text in my store never gets initialize and always return undefined
2. component did not re render from state changes

---

```
function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{props.text && props.text}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => props.setText()}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    text: state.text
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setText: () => dispatch(setCurrentText())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

reducer

```
const initial_state = {
  text: "hello"
};

export const textReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "text-change":
      console.log("in here reducer", action);

      return { ...state, text: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action

```
export const setCurrentText = () => {
  return {
    type: "text-change",
    payload: "change now"
  };
};
```

Comment: have you created a store with your reducer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {textReducer} from './reducer';

function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{props.text && props.text}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => props.setText()}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    text: state.textReducer.text
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setText: () => dispatch(setCurrentText())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```